# How to build this widget group in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter-layout, card

[The second widget group in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6hPd.png)

I want to know how to build the second widget group in the image provided(Especially how to place that card slightly above the other) without using mediaQuery

(In such a way that it will remain in ratio despite of screen being tilted to a wider screen)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Try a stack with positioned container . Should respect the position you specify on all platforms